# Nuxtjs pre rendered in combination with spa

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api, static-pages

In nuxt.js I want to serve first pages that you get with "nuxt generate", and after it's ready to run spa way of functioning. I see it's possible(VuePress did it), my question is, is that possible with nuxt and how?